# Null pointer exception for spring annotation autowired field

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I've referred to all other questions similar to this one but none of the solution seems to be working for me. I'm using spring annotations for autowiring but getting a null pointer exception for the autowired field. Below is the code:

**ValidateResouce.java**

```
@Component
@Path("v1")
@Api(value = "v1", description = "Validate API")
public class ValidateResource {

@Autowired
ValidateController validateController;

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path(value = "/validate/{CAN}")
public Response validateCustomerNumber(@PathParam("CAN") String CAN) {
    validateController.validateCustomerNumber(CAN); ---> //getting a null pointer exception here
    return Response.ok().build();
}
}
```

**ValidateController.java**

```
@Component
public class ValidateController {

@Autowired
REPBillingService repBillingService;

public Integer validateCustomerNumber(String CAN) {
    int result;
    if(!repBillingService.isDelinquentCAN(CAN)){
        if(repBillingService.isDemoUser(CAN)){
            result = 5;
        }
        else {
            result = 0;
        }
    }
    else {
        result = getDelinquentStatus(CAN);
    }
    return result;
}

private Integer getDelinquentStatus(String CAN){
    int result;
    DelinquentStatus delinquentStatus = repBillingService.getDelinquentStatus(CAN);
    Integer graceValue = delinquentStatus.getGrace();
    String statusValue = delinquentStatus.getStatus();

    if(delinquentStatus != null) {
        if (graceValue > 0) {
            repBillingService.updateGrace(delinquentStatus.getID());
            result = 1;
        } else if (statusValue == "I") {
            result = 4;
        } else {
            result = 3;
        }
    }
    else {
        result = 3;
    }
    return result;
}
}
```

**REPBillingService.java**

```
@Component
public class REPBillingService {

@Autowired
DelinquentStatus delinquentStatus;

public boolean isDelinquentCAN(String CAN){
    return false;
}

public boolean isDemoUser(String CAN){
    return false;
}

public DelinquentStatus getDelinquentStatus(String CAN){
//        call DelinquentStatus api
    return delinquentStatus;
}

public void updateGrace(Integer ID) {
    // update call
}
}
```

I have added `<context:annotation-config />` and `<context:component-scan base-package...` in my **applicationContext.xml**

Can someone please tell me where am I going wrong ?

The stack trace of the error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jersey-servlet] in context with path [/isg] threw exception [java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.intuit.ptg.lacerte.resource.ValidateResource.validateCustomerNumber(ValidateResource.java:35)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Show us the stack trace

Comment: Can you recheck base-package scanning, because at runtime spring is not able to load this bean into spring container

Comment: How `ValidateResource` bean is instantiated and put in the context?

Comment: @Lesiak Added the stack trace

Comment: @AlexSalauyou I have the <context:component-scan base-package="package of ValidateResource" /> in my applicationContext.xml

Comment: are you scanning ValidateController  class in your application context file

Comment: Try using @ RestController for ValidateResouce and @ Service for ValidateController classes instead of using @ Component.

Comment: @RavatTailor I have specified the base package in the context:component-scan in applicationContext.xml. This base package should cover both ValidateResource and ValidateController